# Can you create a JavaScript string without using ' or " quotes?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a JS file with some XML in it, where the XML is supposed to get converted to a word by the server.

E.g.

```
var ip = "<lang:cond><lang:when test="$(VAR{'ip_addr'})">$(VAR{'ip_addr'})</lang:when></lang:cond>";
```

This gets converted to:

```
var ip = "192.168.0.0";
```

However, in case the server doesn't work as intended, I don't want there to be a syntax error, and this is VERY important.  Currently there would be a syntax error because the language uses both types of quotes.  I can't think of a way to get around this, but perhaps there's another way to do quotes in JavaScript?  Or to create a string?

For example, in Python I'd use triple quotes:

```
ip = """<lang:cond><lang:when test="$(VAR{'ip_addr'})">$(VAR{'ip_addr'})</lang:when></lang:cond>"""
```

Anyone have a bright idea?

Comment: Why don't you retrieve the XML separately? This way you would not need to bother with quotes.

Comment: String can't be created without quotes. Alternative way to create a string in javascript is var str=new String("ok"), str has now value "ok".

Comment: @Heera - Strings certainly _can_ be created without quotes. `String.fromCharCode(72,69,76,76,79)` produces the string `HELLO`. (I know this isn't at all helpful in this case, but anyway...)

Comment: Well, smart answer and appreciate it but as you said not helpful in this case.

Answer (score 35):

I have had to create strings without quotes for a project as well. We were delivering executable client javascript to the browser for an internal website. The receiving end strips double and single quotes when displayed. One way I have found to get around quotes is by declaring my string as a regular expression.

```
var x = String(/This contains no quotes/);
x = x.substring(1, x.length-1);
x;
```

Comment: Wow. This is a neat trick. It helped me solve a problem where I needed to represent "a string within a string, within a string, within a string." :) I was using PHP to return a JSON string (1), which included some HTML `</a>` tags (2), one of which needed to include an `onclick=""` attribute (3) that invoked a JavaScript method handler that required a string parameter (4). I was running out of ways to embed quotes and yet not break the JS parser, when this clever trick gave me a third way representing everything. Radical, man. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! This was so helpful you can't even imagine.

Comment: `/This contains no quotes/.source`

Answer (score 10):

Using **String** prototype:

```
String(/This contains no quotes/).substring(1).slice(0,-1)
```

Using **String.fromCharCode**

```
String.fromCharCode(72,69,76,76,79)
```

Generate Char Codes for this:

```
var s = "This contains no quotes";
var result = [];
for (i=0; i<s.length; i++)
{
    result.push(s.charCodeAt(i));
}
result
```

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript, you can escape either type of quote with a `\`.

For example:

```
var str = "This is a string with \"embedded\" quotes.";
var str2 = 'This is a string with \'embedded\' quotes.';
```

In particular, your block of JavaScript code should be converted to:

```
var ip = "<lang:cond><lang:when test=\"$(VAR{'ip_addr'})\">$(VAR{'ip_addr'})</lang:when></lang:cond>";
```

In general, I always prefer to escape the quotes instead of having to constantly switch quote types, depending upon what type of quotes may be used within.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't, because the XML for some reason doesn't work with escaped quotes.

Comment: @Jeff - when the contents are read out of the String by JavaScript, the escaped quotes will be unescaped, and the XML will no longer have the escaped quotes.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem. Someone suggested looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings which proved helpful. After reading about half the article, it stated that you can create strings with the backward tick character. (`)

Try this :)

```js
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = `'|'|'|"|"`
```

```html
<div id="test" style="font-size:3em;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a string without using a single or double quote, as even calling the `String()` prototype object directly still requires you to pass it the string.

Inside XML you would use CDATA, but inside JS you'll have to just escape the `'\"strings\"'` `"\'appropriately\'"`

Comment: Of course you can create a string without using quotes. I'm not saying it would be at all helpful for this problem, but still `String.fromCharCode(72,69,76,76,79)` produces the string `HELLO`.

Comment: Aha, fantastic idea. Now that you mention that vector I bet you could you a few JavaScript obfuscation techniques to do this.