# Weebly inserts backslashes into my javascript before forward slashes

Tags: javascript, html, r-markdown, weebly

As far as I can tell, any time I insert Javascript containing the pattern `/</*` into a Weebly page using "Embed Code", it gets replaced with `/<\/*` on the published page.

For instance, this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hljs=new function(p){return p.replace(/</gm, "&lt;"}
</script>
```

Shows up like this when I inspect the final page in my browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hljs=new function(p){return p.replace(/<\/gm, "&lt;"}
</script>
```

This is a problem, because it seems to be screwing up regular expressions that are intended to do syntax-highlighting on code I'm displaying on the page. I'm using html + Javascript generated from R Markdown. When I open the html files in my browser they look fine, but when I look at the version I put up on weebly, there is no syntax highlighting and I get a SyntaxError (`Invalid regular expression flags` in Chrome, `unmatched ) in regular expression` in FireFox). If I view the source, the only difference is the extra backslashes.

Anyone have a work-around?

Update: Turns out this was a symptom of a different problem. When Rmarkdown generates html, it includes a `<head></head>` block. It's important for that to go in the actual header of the page. Pasting the whole thing into the "embed code" box, like I was doing, shoves everything into the body. So the real solution is to go to the design tab and add the Rmarkdown header code into the header of the file corresponding to the page layout you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `new RegExp(string, flags);` syntax.

`<script type="text/javascript">
    var hljs=new function(p){return p.replace(new RegExp("<", "gm"), "&lt;"}
</script>`

That may avoid Weebly forcing the character escaping.

Comment: This solved the problem for the regexes! There were also some pure strings that were causing the same problem (any reference to "</script>", for instance). I used the String.fromCharCode workaround described here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981009/can-you-create-a-javascript-string-without-using-or-quotes) to solve those. Of course, this whole syntax error problem turned out to be a symptom, rather than the cause. The real problem was that the header wasn't getting put into the actual page header.