# How to slice a number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've the following code snippet,

```
var code = 895804220010013030;
var last = code.slice(-2);
var n = last.includes(00, 01, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31 );

if (n===true) {
  alert(n)
} else {
 alert('false')
}
```

But it invokes syntax error, the only way it works well is to put the quotes to the numbers

```
var code = 895804220010013030;
```

but I need to run it without putting the quotes.

Comment: Cause Number doesn't have a `slice` function. That's why you are gettings that error. Also `includes` works with `someString.includes(elementToSearch, ?fromIndex)` this signature.

Comment: `slice` method is only defined for strings and array-like objects, not for numbers

Comment: Your code will never work without using a string (as pointed out by @pai.not.pi - here's a test to show why:  `var x = 895804220010013030; console.log(x);` and `console.log(895804220010013030 === 895804220010013000)`   (where 895...030 === 895...000)

Comment: String without quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981009/can-you-create-a-javascript-string-without-using-or-quotes

Answer (score 5):

change this :

```
var last = code.slice(-2);
```

to this :

```
var last = String(code).slice(-2);
```

or this :

```
var last = code.toString().slice(-2);
```

**WHY?**

because [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) is method of `String` not a `Number`. It extracts a section of a string and returns it as a new string, without modifying the original string.

**UPDATE**

based on the first comment.

```
var code = 130031;
var last = code.toString().slice(-2);
var n = [00, 01, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31].includes(last);
```

For more information read about [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes(element,index))

Comment: he include is generating an error does not take the numbers correctly. in this example it is seen that it does not detect the number 31 function myFunction

Comment: I answered according to your current issue **but it creates me syntax error**. You have another issue with `include`.

Comment: Please, read more about [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Another option to convert to a string:  `var str = number + "";`

Comment: @freedomn-m, yes but is there a difference between **Coercion** and **Parsing** in JS ?

Answer (score 1):

If your root concern is creating a string without any quotes: here is a technique:

```js
var x = String(/895804220010013030/);
x = x.substring(1, x.length-1);
x;
```

You can check the length to be confident about it.

From an older post's answer: [Can you create a JavaScript string without using ' or " quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981009/can-you-create-a-javascript-string-without-using-or-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Have to edit the start of the answer since I just realized that the number you're trying to capture in the `code` variable is actually greater than the [max **safe** integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) value available in JS.

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is not a method defined on the Number type. You can choose to store the code as a `string` and that will make life easier for you,

```
var code = '895804220010013030';
var last = Number(code.slice(-2));
var n = [00, 01, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31].includes(last);

if (n===true) {
  alert(n)
} else{
 alert('false')
}
```

Additionally, there are better ways to write the `if-else` since the value of `n` is going to be a boolean as `includes` will always return a true or false.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes),

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

Either,

```
if (n) {
  alert(n);
} else {
  alert(false);
}
```

or simply,

```
alert(n);
```

Comment: the include is generating an error does not take the numbers correctly.


in this example it is seen that it does not detect the number 31

function myFunction() {

var code = 130031;
var last = code.toString().slice(-2);

alert(last);

var n = last.includes(00, 01, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31 );
alert(n)
if (n==true) {
  alert(n)
} else{
 alert('false')
}

  }

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin haha didn't realize :D thanks, have updated my answer :)